# How to open in new tab in GCP console search bar?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, google-cloud-platform

It is very handy to have the GCP console search bar, and I can scroll down to a particular  service. However, I cannot open it in new tab, despite trying various keyboard combinations (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd>, <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd>, etc.)

This is a sharp contrast with AWS console which can.

[image]